# What does the + signify in this Date shim?

Tags: javascript, date

Just ran into [Date.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) and was wondering what the meaning of the **+** in **+**(new Date) is.

```
if (!Date.now) {  
  Date.now = function now() {  
    return +(new Date);  
  };  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29). It converts its operand to a number. From MDN:

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
>   already. For example, y = +x takes the value of x and assigns that to
>   y; that is, if x were 3, y would get the value 3 and x would retain
>   the value 3; but if x were the string "3", y would also get the value
>   3.

In this case, since the operand is a date, the number will be a number of milliseconds since midnight on the 1st Jan 1970.

It is effectively the same as writing:

```
Number(new Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

That converts the date to a number.

A date as a number is the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 (also called Unix time). This is, naturally, exactly what `Date.now()` is supposed to return.

Answer (score 1):

It just converts date to number, number will be amount of milliseconds from the epoch. From the ECMAScript specification:

> 11.4.6 Unary + Operator
>   The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.
>   The production UnaryExpression: + UnaryExpression is evaluated as follows: 
>   1. Evaluate UnaryExpression. 
>   2. Call GetValue(Result(1)). 
>   3. Call ToNumber(Result(2)). 
>   4. Return Result(3).

Answer (score 0):

the unary + operator type-converts its operand to a number and because it does not do any additional mathematical operations it is the fastest method for type-converting into a number. So thats what it is doing